# Run Kotest tests from Bazel

Tags: kotlin, gradle, bazel, kotest

I'm trying to migrate a big monorepo that's currently using Gradle, and in which all tests are written in Kotest.

I'm struggling to find a way to run these tests from Bazel.

Any example out there? has somebody achieved it?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can run kotest tests as you run Java Tests.

Our strategy is two-fold. First we compile all the relevant test code bits to a `kt_jvm_library`. We then use that library as a dependency of the test rule using the `native.java_test` rule. This is the macro we use in our prototype repository (stripped down, since our version contains company-specific stuff):

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:jvm.bzl", "kt_jvm_library")
load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "artifact")

def nx_kt_jvm_test(
        name,
        test_package,
        args = [],
        srcs = [],
        deps = [],
        runtime_deps = [],
        resources = [],
        size = "medium",
        tags = [],
        **kwargs):
    main_test_name = name
    main_test_args = args + [
        "--fail-if-no-tests",
        "--disable-banner",
        "--disable-ansi-colors",
        "--select-package={test_package}".format(test_package = test_package),
    ]
    main_test_resources = [] + resources
    kt_jvm_library(
        name = main_test_name + "_lib",
        srcs = srcs,
        deps = deps,
        resources = main_test_resources,
        testonly = True,
        **kwargs
    )

    main_test_tags = []
    native.java_test(
        name = main_test_name,
        main_class = "org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher",
        use_testrunner = False,
        tags = main_test_tags,
        size = size,
        args = main_test_args,
        stamp = 0,
        runtime_deps = runtime_deps + [
            ":" + main_test_name + "_lib",
            artifact("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console-standalone"),  # keep
            artifact("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core"),
            artifact("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api"),
            artifact("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5-jvm"),
            artifact("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api"),
            artifact("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params"),
            artifact("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl"),
        ],
    )
```

Generally, this works well-enough in CI but the IDE integration is not good. E.g. no support for running individual test methods. Therefore, I'd love an improved version.